# Using defaultProps with withStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a component using material-ui withStylers and defaultProps, but when i try to use the props of the component, in the styles objects, i never get the value of my default props, only get the value if it is passed to the component.
My component structure is something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = theme => ({
    ClassTest: {
        anyAttr: props => console.log(props) 
    }
});

const Test = ({classes}) => {
    return (
        <span className={classes.ClassTest}/>
    );
};

Test.defaultProps = {
    val2: "hey"
};

Test.propTypes = {
    val1: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    val2: PropTypes.string,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Test);
```

And i use like this

```
<Test val1="Hello">
```

I expect that the console log show something like this:

```
{
  classes: {...},
  val1: "Hello",
  val2: "hey"
}
```

But instead, i got this

```
{
  classes: {...},
  val1: "Hello"
}
```

If I call the component that way:

```
<Test val1="Hello" val2="hey">
```

I got this:

```
{
  classes: {...},
  val1: "Hello",
  val2: "hey"
}
```

So, the styles object shouldn't give the the value of the props, considering defaultProps? I'm doin it correctly or i miss something?

I'm using the following versions:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.3.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
```

And I'm basing on this part of the documentation
https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withStyles` is wrapping `Test` in a higher-order-component and has no visibility to the default props of `Test`. `withStyles` is adding to the properties of `Test` (injecting a `classes` prop), so the default props for `Test` can't be determined until after `withStyles` finishes its work (e.g. if `Test` had a default prop for `classes`, it wouldn't be leveraged when `withStyles` is providing `classes`, but the default could be leveraged when **not** wrapped by `withStyles`).

In the code below, I demonstrate three different approaches:

1. The first is the approach you tried which doesn't work because the default props aren't visible to `withStyles`.
2. The second approach applies the default props to the HOC returned by `withStyles`.
3. The third approach uses `makeStyles`/`useStyles` instead of `withStyles` which makes it possible to still have the default props on the initial component rather than the HOC.

All three approaches work when `bgcolor` is specified explicitly (orange), but only approaches 2 and 3 successfully see the default prop value.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  test: {
    backgroundColor: props => props.bgcolor
  }
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

const ApproachThatDoesNotWork = ({ classes }) => {
  return <div className={classes.test}>ApproachThatDoesNotWork</div>;
};
ApproachThatDoesNotWork.defaultProps = {
  bgcolor: "lightgreen"
};
const StyledApproachThatDoesNotWork = withStyles(styles)(
  ApproachThatDoesNotWork
);

const DefaultPropsOnStyledHOC = ({ classes }) => {
  return <div className={classes.test}>DefaultPropsOnStyledHOC</div>;
};
const StyledDefaultPropsOnStyledHOC = withStyles(styles)(
  DefaultPropsOnStyledHOC
);
StyledDefaultPropsOnStyledHOC.defaultProps = {
  bgcolor: "pink"
};

const MakeStylesAndUseStyles = props => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={classes.test}>MakeStylesAndUseStyles</div>;
};
MakeStylesAndUseStyles.defaultProps = {
  bgcolor: "lightblue"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledApproachThatDoesNotWork />
      <StyledApproachThatDoesNotWork bgcolor="orange" />
      <StyledDefaultPropsOnStyledHOC />
      <StyledDefaultPropsOnStyledHOC bgcolor="orange" />
      <MakeStylesAndUseStyles />
      <MakeStylesAndUseStyles bgcolor="orange" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit styles using defaultProps]